# More efficient way to display big amount of data on c# from sql server?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Currently this is our method to display data table from sql server, the table stored in server have several columns including ProjectFile and Culture, we only want to display the data with user specified projectfile and culture:

```
private void showData(string[] selectedProject, string[] selectedCulure)
 {
        //the sql procedure will select data of specific culture and projectfile from table,it has two parameters:@culture and @projectfile
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("PROCEDURE_GETData", m_conn);
        com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        for (int i = 0; i < selectedProject.Length; i++)
        {
            com.Parameters.Add("@ProjectFile", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value =   selectedProject[i];
            for (int m = 0; m < selectedCulure.Length; m++)
            {
                com.Parameters.Add("@Culture", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = selectedCulure[m];

                try
                {
                    m_conn.Open();
                    dataView.DataSource = com.ExecuteReader();
                    dataView.DataBind();
                    if (dataView.Rows.Count == 0)
                    {
                        dataView.EmptyDataText = "No data found, please select another project or culture. ";
                        dataView.DataBind();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Response.Write("Error Occur: " + ex.ToString());
                }
                finally
                {
                    m_conn.Close();
                    m_conn.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem of this method is it is very slow, and it cannot successfully create table when user chooses multiple projectfile or culture, what's the better way to display data in this case?

Comment: The first thing you need to do is move the sql connection open/close outside of the for loops.

Comment: @gunr2171, thanks for suggestion, I'll definitely try it. Maybe my title is not clear, but it's not only about improving the code, the code currently fails to load data if user chooses multiple Culture or projectfile, and I don't know where's the problem.

Comment: @SSilicon, if your code does not work (which I was not clear on) DO NOT go to Code Review. But can you tell us more about how the code does not work. What do you input and what happens?

Comment: If I want to load the table with multiple Culture or projectfile selected, the asp.net page will not respond to the code, and nothing will happen.

Comment: Well yes it's going through each combination of project and culture in two for loops, selecting everything binding it and then as long as there are some results, throwing them all away and doing the next one!   Are Project and culture tuples e.g you want P1 and C1 Union P2 and C2 or do you want P1 | P2 | C1 | C2?

Comment: See if you can pass the projects and cultures as an XML to SP. Let SP returns all the data at once. That way it will provide best performance.

Comment: I have a question about disposing the m_conn object inside the loop: doesn't it throw an exception when trying to open m_conn again?

Comment: @Tony Hopkinson, thanks for the advice! I want project and culture to be (P1 or P2) and (C1 or C2), for example, I want to see the data displayed on table are either P1 with C1 or C2, or P2 with C1 or C2

Comment: Get rid of the for loops, you want Project in ('P1','P2') and Culture in ('C1','C2'). Better still follow @BhasyakaruluKottakota advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The failure is happening for 2 (maybe 3) reasons:

1. Don't use an instance member as the SQL connection.  Wrap all your code in a

   ```
   using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString)
   ```
2. Reconstruct the `SqlCommand` inside the innermost loop every time.
3. It looks like you're rebinding each dataset from multiple calls to the same dataview.  I don't have much experience with those.  I typically use `reader["myField"]` and construct local objects, so this may not be an issue.